# Limit max width of image from rich text using Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, css, html, richtextarea

I have two Rich Text Area fields named Description__c and Operational_Disposition__c. My goal is to limit the width of images inside these two fields to the max of 600px. I tried creating this trigger:

```
trigger ResizeTestImage on Test__c (before insert, before update) {

Test__c test = Trigger.new[0];

string newTag = '<img style = "max-width: 600px;"';

if (test.Description__c != null) {

        test.Description__c = test.Description__c.replace('<img', newTag);

        system.debug('field after ' + test.Description__c);

    }

if (test.Operational_Disposition__c != null) {

        test.Operational_Disposition__c = test.Operational_Disposition__c.replace('<img', newTag);

        system.debug('field after ' + test.Operational_Disposition__c);   

    }

}
```

But when I try using max-width, it simply ignores it.

[image: Style]

When I use other styles, such as width=100%, height=450px, etc... it works normally, only styles like max-width, min-width that it ignores

Comment: so Description__c is a rich text field?  what does the database value look like before and after (use SOQL to query)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.